# Where to look for the error in the update database statement in line 331 in my program

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have two issues, but I am only working on correcting one currently. In my program on line 331, when I execute it I get the error (*catch statement*) that there is an error with the SQL statement. It is identical to the others (that I see) and I am not seeing the error. Here is a snippet of the section that gives an error. I should just be able to update mysql database, just as the other sections do, this one errors. Where should I look? Something did not post correctly, I am looking at that too, sorry.

```
    //String st = "DELETE FROM student WHERE Description = 'Michael'";
    // String st = “UPDATE student SET Description = + ‘Michael’ WHERE studentID = ‘123’”;
    String studentID;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    double gpa;
    String status;
    String mentor;
    String level;
    String thesisTitle;
    String thesisAdvisor;
    String company;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    // print statements to match the database input 

    System.out.println("Now let's update a record");
    System.out.println("Please enter the student ID of the record you want to update >");
    studentID = in.next();
    System.out.println("Please enter the new First Name >");
    firstName = in.next();
    System.out.println("Please enter the new Last Name >");
    lastName = in.next();
    System.out.println("Please enter the new GPA[X.XX] >");
    gpa = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Please enter the new Status [Active or Inactive] >");
    status = in.next();
    System.out.println("Please enter the new mentor >");
    mentor = in.next();
    System.out.println("Please enter the new level >");
    level = in.next();
    System.out.println("Please enter the new thesis Title >");
    thesisTitle = in.next();
    System.out.println("Please enter the new thesis Advisor's name >");
    thesisAdvisor = in.next();
    System.out.println("Please enter the new Company Name >");
    company = in.next();




//      stmt.executeUpdate("Update student Set studentID='" + studentID + "', firstName='" + firstName + "', lastName='" + lastName + "', gpa=" + gpa + "', status='" + status + "', mentor='" + mentor  + "', level='" + level + "', theseisTitle='" + thesisTitle + "', thesisAdvisor='" + thesisAdvisor + "', company='" + company + "WHERE studentID = '" + studentID + " '");





    stmt.executeUpdate("Update student Set studentID='" + studentID + "',firstName'" + firstName + "', lastName='" + lastName + "', gpa=" + gpa + "', status='" + status + "', mentor='" + mentor  + "', level='" + level + "', theseisTitle='" + thesisTitle + "', thesisAdvisor='" + thesisAdvisor + "', company='" + company + "WHERE studentID = '" + studentID + " '");

    // Close the statement and the connection

    stmt.close();
    conn.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("ERROR: Either cannot connect to the DB " + " or error with the SQL statement");
}
```

Comment: Why not print the exception and see where that takes you?

Comment: Missing an `=` in `firstName'" + firstName`, should be `firstName='" + firstName`

Comment: Sidenote: Why don't you use `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: instead of swallowing the exception, print it: `System.err.println(e);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one problem with your query is that it produces syntax error on the `firstname`

```
stmt.executeUpdate("Update student 
                    Set studentID='" + studentID + "',
                        firstName'" + firstName + "',                                          
                                 ^ here
```

Another is, it is vulnerable with `SQL injection`. Please do parameterized your query, use `PreparedStatement`, example

```
String updateQuery = ""
        + "UPDATE student "
        + "SET    firstname = ?, "
        + "       lastname = ?, "
        + "       gpa = ?, "
        + "       status = ?, "
        + "       mentor = ?, "
        + "       level = ?, "
        + "       theseistitle = ?, "
        + "       thesisadvisor = ?, "
        + "       company = ? "
        + "WHERE  studentid = ? ";

PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(updateQuery);
pstmt.setString(1,firstName)
pstmt.setString(2,lastName)
pstmt.setInt(3,gpa)
pstmt.setString(4,status)
pstmt.setString(5,mentor)
pstmt.setString(6,level)
pstmt.setString(7,thesisTitle)
pstmt.setString(8,thesisAdvisor)
pstmt.setString(9,company)
pstmt.setString(10,studentID)
```

Why do we use `PreparedStatement`?

- to protect against `SQL Injection`
- to protect against `SQL Injection`
- to make the code more readable especially when you have large query

SOURCE

- [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)
- [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: Thanks for the second pair of eyes and finding the problem. And the SQL injection suggestion is a GREAT one. I am aware of what sql injection is, I just have not studied yet how to mitigate them. I will read up and work this solution in.

Answer (score 1):

One problem I see is that you are missing a `=` at `firstName'" + firstName +`.

Answer (score 0):

just before the WHERE clause you have omitted a closing quote after appending company.